# Recent post on single page from specyfic category

Tags: recent-posts

i have problem.
I use this code before comment form.

```
<?php

global $post;

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

        <?php the_permalink(); ?><?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I have in `single.php`:

1 -- post content

2 -- recent post

3 -- form comment

But when i comment something my comment is not on post but was added to last **recent post**.
How can i do this?

I tried to use this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'category__not_in' => array( 23, 24 )
);

$recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $recent ) . '">Latest Post</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `wp_reset_postdata` after outputting your recent posts.

Comment: Ya that is what i need. Thx.